# Smart way to solve $\dot{x}=x^3+1.5x^2+0.5x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

How to solve the following problem:   $$\dot{x}=x^3+1.5x^2+0.5x$$

Obviouly, this is a separable nonlinear homogenous first order ODE. So

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^3+1.5x^2+0.5x}=\int dt$$ Then it is a hard work here for integration. Is there any smart way to solve this tedious problem?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I guess there might be a change of variables that transforms this into a Bernoulli-type equation (by eliminating x^2).

Comment: Partial fractions seem a likely way forward.

Comment: You could substitute $x=v-\frac{1}{2}$, and then obtain $\frac{dv}{dt}=v^3-\frac{v}{4}$, which is easier to do a partial fraction decomposition on than the one you have.

Comment: @projectilemotion you just beat me to it! Worked out that using x = v-c, you have 3/2 - 3c = 0 so c = 1/2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that 
$$x^3+1.5x^2+0.5x= x(x+1)(x+1/2)$$ 
and by the [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition):
$$\frac{1}{x^3+1.5x^2+0.5x}=\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{4}{x+1/2}.$$
Therefore after the integration  we get
$$2\ln\left|\frac{x(x+1)}{(2x+1)^2}\right|=t+c$$
that is
$$x(x+1)=Ce^{t/2}(2x+1)^2.$$
Now solve the quadratic equation in $x$. Can you take it from here?

P.S. Don't forget the stationary solutions: $x=0$, $x=-1$ and $x=-1/2$!